# Vue.js button resets after page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a task list with a completed button for each task. The button resets to "complete" instead of staying in "completed" status whenever I refresh the page. It needs to stay in the changed state even after refresh. Below is the vue.js code I am using. I am using Laravel framework, vue.js and PHP.

```
<template>

<div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary ml-4" @click="followUser" v-text="buttonText"></button>

</div>

</template>



<script>




export default {

    props: ['taskId', 'follows'],



    mounted() {

        console.log('Component mounted.')

    },



    data: function () {

        return {

            status: this.follows,

        }

     },



    methods: {

        followUser() {

            axios.post('/follow/' + this.taskId)

                .then(response => {

                    this.status = ! this.status;



                    console.log(response.data);

                })

                .catch(errors => {

                    if (errors.response.status == 401) {

                        window.location = '/login';

                    }

                });

        }

     },



    computed: {

        buttonText() {

            return (this.status) ? 'completed'  : 'complete';


        }

    }

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Depending on what you need, you need somewhere to indicate the status is `completed`, most likely from database of the backend side. Then when you render the button component, check the status  and alter the style of button as you want.

Comment: Your initial value for `status` is taken from `follows` property. Are you sure that it is updated somehow when you call `axios.post('/follow/' + this.taskId)`?

Comment: Do you mean this way?

Comment: computed: {
if ('is_complete' == true) {
            buttonText() {

                return (this.status) = "completed";

            }}
else {
            buttonText()
            {
                return (this.status) = "complete";

            }
        }

Comment: @Lana Please check above code

Comment: @ozeol No, the code above is something... I don't know what you wanted to say by this code. What I ment talking about `follows`: your component has a property `follows`. And in your `data` you set `status`  to `follows`. This will be executed on page refresh. Then, according to your code, when you click on the button you call API and on resolve you toggle `status`. But when you refresh the page `status` will be initialized again by 'follows'. So, if your API call doesn't lead to changing of `follows` you will get the old value.

Comment: @Lana This is my API call: Route::post('follow/{task}', 'FollowsController@store');

Comment: What would I need to add?

Comment: @jsmith The code in your question describes a component, let's say it calls `complete-button`. This component according to your code has a property `follows`. So you place a button like this `<complete-button :follows="some_variable_in_the parent_component"></complete-button>`. How do you get `some_variable_in_the parent_component`? Is it updated after your API call?

Comment: @Lana I don't think there is a parent component unless you mean the FollowsController.php file? The only vue component is shown in the code above.

Comment: @jsmith If you don't have parent component then how do you pass `follows` property to the component described in the question?

Comment: @Lana sorry so it passed the task id from index.blade.php     <div class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3">
                                                    

                                                    <follow-button task-id="{{ $task->id }}" follows="{{ $follows }}" offautocomplete></follow-button>
                                                </div>

Comment: @jsmith ok, did you check with `console.log()` the value of `$follows`? how do you get the value of `$follows`? Are you sure that API call effects the value of `$follows`? It must be `true` because you initialise `status` with `status: this.follows` and then calculate your button text  `return (this.status) ? 'completed'  : 'complete';` If `$follows` is `false` then status is `false` and then button text is 'complete'